# Limiting Argparse Help Output

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I'm using argparse to handle command-line arguments inside an application I'm developing.  As it stands, everything works as advertised.  However, I'm having an issue with the individual argument's help formatting.

```
optional arguments:
  -k API_KEY, --key API_KEY
                        API Key to use when querying/updating records
  -e EMAIL, --email EMAIL
                        Email to use when querying/updating records
```

In the help formatting above, I'm looking at how to solve the duplicate argument variable names (i.e. `-k API_KEY, --key API_KEY`).  This seems redundant and leads to the help formatting being on multiple lines vs a single, continuous line.  Here is the relevant code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    parser_required=parser.add_argument_group('Required Arguments')
    parser_required.add_argument('-k', '--key', dest='api_key', type=str, required=False, help='API Key to use when querying/updating records')
    parser_required.add_argument('-e', '--email', dest='email', type=str, required=False, help='Email to use when querying/updating records')
```

I'm not totally sure how I can achieve this, though.  Here is the desired output.

```
optional arguments:
  -k, --key             API Key to use when querying/updating records
  -e, --email           Email to use when querying/updating records
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366369/python-argparse-lots-of-choices-results-in-ugly-help-output  discusses various options.  Besides the simplest `metavar` solution, you can customize the `HelpFormatter` class.  Suggestions on how to do that have been given in several SO questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `metavar=''` in each argument:

```
add_argument('-k', '--key', metavar='', ...)
```

Metavars are `API_KEY` and `EMAIL` in your example.